Azure DevOps Microsoft hosted MAC agent - XCode account signing
This is about the Automatic signing mobile app using an MS-hosted MAC agent -> Methods using Xcode, Fastlane, or cmd pipeline tasks.
I saw several posts and understand that I can upload profiles along with certificates; app signing works. I am using that already for a couple of them. However, I am trying to understand the possibility of true automatic app signing without profiles uploaded. We have several app variants and their flavors, so managing profiles manually is a maintenance overhead. I am trying to migrate builds from locally hosted MACs to Microsoft-hosted MACs agents here.
To do automatic app signing, Xcode must be logged in with an Apple developer account. Is there a command-line method or Azure DevOps yaml task that supports Xcode Apple developer account signing in before building/archiving/signing the package?

I am afraid that there is no method can sign in the Apple developer account  before signing the package.
When we use Microsoft-hosted agent, there are no pre-configured or cached credentials and provisioning profiles in the machine environment.
In this case, we cannot achieve true automatic app signing. When using Automatic signing method in Xcode Task, we still need to add the Install Apple Certificate task and Install Apple Provisioning Profile task to install certificates and provisioning profiles prior to the Xcode build.
And automatic signing only works for development builds in Azure DevOps. You cannot use auto signing in a DevOps pipeline for distribution(ad hoc, app store, etc).
We need to set the development method in the ExportOptions.plist
For example:
....
 <key>method</key>
  <string>development</string>
....

YAML sample:
steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'my-secure-file.p12' 
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: 'my-provisioning-profile.mobileprovision' 
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: 'App'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/App.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'auto'
    exportOptions: 'plist'
    exportOptionsPlist: 'path-to-exportoptions'
    exportPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/iOS'

In Azure DevOps, we can always manually sign your IOS package by specifying the $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY) and $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID) variable to Xcode task.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Sign your Apple iOS, macOS, tvOS, or watchOS app

OK, thanks. As I mentioned, I am using this similar for some builds. I am attempting to make it work with the xcodebuild flag allowProvisioningUpdates (similar to what I am doing in the self-hosted Mac).

@JijoJohn Yes. I know this flag. But when you use this flag, it may still show the following error: error: No Accounts: Add a new account in Accounts settings. No profiles for 'xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.xx' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching To make sure it can work, I still suggest that we can use manually sign in Azure DevOps.

the error for me is path/AAABBB.xcodeproj: No Account for Team "XXXRRRUUU". Add a new account in Accounts settings or verify that your accounts have valid credentials. (in target

@JijoJohn Yes. This is the similar issue. The cause of the issue could be that we cannot  can sign in the Apple developer account before signing the package and there are no pre-configured or cached credentials and provisioning profiles in the machine environment. You need to use task to install Certificate and provisioning profiles before Xcode. At the same time, you need to use Plist file to let it work.  I have encountered similar problems before. I can directly use manually sign method to solve it.

I know that works. The whole point of my question is to avoid provisioning profile management. I do not want to re-upload every profile when it expires or, new or for any other reason, have to do with 10-15 builds in single pipeline run in loops. The enterprise cert has at least three years of validity, no issue there, which is common for all builds.

@JijoJohn Thanks for your feedback. I can fully understand your requirement. But I am afraid that there is no method can achieve this in Microsoft-hosted Agent for the time being. Whether signing automatically or manually, we need to upload the profile and install it before the Xcode task. I think that we can pre-config the environment on self-hosted agents to skip the profile uploads step.
